# Labeling GridLines: Callout, Graphics or Labeled?

Tags: plotting, grid-lines

I have a `ListPlot` where I plot multiple lists. I would like to highlight specific points on the x axis. I know I can use `GridLines` to render vertical lines at given x values.

Thus the question is how can I do this?

- Should I label a `GridLine`?
- Should I use a `Callout`? If that is the case, can I have one `Callout` for multiple groups? (e.g. highlight the same point on multiple lines with a single blurb?).
- Should I plot a vertical line within `ListPlot` and give that a `Callout`?
- Should I use a `Graphics` primitive, e.g. `Graphics[Line[{{3, -5}, {3, 5}}], PlotRange -> 5, Axes -> True]`

How would I do any of those as they are not examples in the documentation?

Note:

- `Labeled` with `Graphics` works, but not in conjunction with `Show` and `Plot`.
- Appending `Callout[{x,y},"Test",Above]` to one of the lists to plot does not work.
- Adding `{Callout[{x,y},"Test",Above]}` as another list in `ListPlot` produces a single point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Basic Answer

This is a non-ideal solution.
One can make the `GridLines` as shown in the documentation or on other S.E. questions. Then using `Show` add a `ListPlot` with one list containing the desired label, e.g.

```
Show[
  <Other Plotting Things>
  ListPlot[
    {myListOne, myListTwo, {Callout[{x, y}, "my label", Above]}}, 
    <GridLine Specifications>
  ]
]
```

Where x is the same as where the `GridLine`s are specified, and y is the position at which to make the `Callout`.

## Example

Here is a working example:

```
Show[
 Plot[
  {Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
  GridLines ->
   {
    {
     {1, Directive[Thickness -> .001, Black]},
     {3, Directive[Thickness -> .001, Black]}
     },
    {0}
    }, 
  ImageSize -> Large ,
  PlotLabel -> "Labeling GridLines", 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}
  ],
 ListPlot[
  {
   {Callout[{1, 0.5}, "Label One", Right],
    Callout[{3, 0.5}, "Label Two", Right]
    }
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

## Notes

Do you think this is ugly? Me too. You can use all your favorite `Directives` to modify the Callout to make up for it. e.g. in `ListPlot` use `PlotStyle->Opacity[0]` to make the point it renders invisible.

[image]

Ask another question about making a beautiful call to suit your needs.

Comment: it is unfortunate you cannot add a Callout on Gridlines! Great answer, thanks!